# aspnet_compiler won’t compile c# code placed under web application directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnet-compiler

I’ve been using mouse right click in Visual Studio to publish sites for ages and everything worked great except there’s been too much manual works. Recently I changed to using build script to call aspnet_compiler to publish ASP.NET web application. In my build script I would do something like below:

```
sh "#{aspnet_compiler} -p ../src/webapp -v targetDir ./publish –u"
```

My project directory structure looks like this:

```
/build/rakefile.rb
/build/publish/ --published site goes here
/src/website/bll/ --business logic goes here
/src/website/ --aspx pages
/src/website/code/ --some c# code
```

When calling aspnet-compiler everything worked fine except the c# code under **/src/website/code/ would not be compiled**. It seems to me that aspnet-compiler **compiled c# code under bll directory** then **xcopied everything under /src/website/** to the publish directory (including /src/website/code/). I don’t know if I am not using the correct switch calling aspnet-compiler or this is the desired behaviour?

Please help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my own problem.

First of all my rake build script end up looking like this:

```
sh "#{aspnet_compiler} -f -fixednames -u -p ../src/website -v / ./publish"
```

Second the output behaviour of mouse right click on "publish" within Visual Studio is different from calling aspnet_compiler.

Right click publish will:

- directly copy **Global.asax**
- only generate **.dll** and **.pdb** (.pdb file can be deleted if debugging is not required) files under bin directory

where when calling aspnet_compiler:

- will compile Global.asax into **App_global.asax.compiled** and **App_global.asax.dll** under bin directory
- will also generate **PrecompiledApp.config** (this is because I've specified aspx pages should be updatable)

There was a clean up task after publish task that basically deleted anything other than .dll extension under bin.

Anyway now I've learnt something new.

Comment: reference to aspnet_compiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when using aspnet_compiler on build machine (I used MSBuild). The solution for me was to build solution before calling aspnet_compiler.
In MSBuild it looks something like:

```
<MSBuild Projects="$(PhysicalPath)\solutionName.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug"/>
```

You can also use devenv solutionName.sln /build (if not using MSBuild).